# How to use Python to convert columns to rows

Tags: python-3.x, excel, multiple-columns, transformation

I have a csv output file as below (sample data):

Score1  Main_Score  Second_score  LGA   pred
5           0          1          1     0.89
5           1          0          1     0.79

[image]

the answers should be like this;

Score1  ScoreType   LGA   pred
5      Main_Score    1    0.89
5      Second_score  1    0.79

[image]

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is here by using if-else.

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f:
    #load csv
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]
    data.pop(0) #delete header

    #convert
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(data[i])
        score_type = "MainScore" if int(data[i][1]) == 0 else "SecondScore" # <- convert it here
        data[i] = [data[i][0], score_type, data[i][3], data[i][4]]

    #save csv
    data.insert(0, ['Source1', 'ScoreType', 'LGA', 'pred']) #add header
    with open('output.csv', 'w',newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)
```

input csv:

```
Source1, Main_Score, Second_Score, LGA, pred
5, 0, 1, 1, 0.89 
5, 1, 0, 1, 0.79
```

output csv:

```
Source1,ScoreType,LGA,pred
5,MainScore, 1, 0.89 
5,SecondScore, 1, 0.79
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, I cant hardcode "Score_type". Because I have 105 different columns which need to be transposed into rows. I know that, my question gives very limited info. Just wanted to how to transpose dynamically without hardcoding the column name

Comment: So, Do you mean that the input csv data have 105 ScoreTypes? Does the output csv data consist of only four columns, [Score1, Scoretype LGA pred] ?

Comment: output csv consist 103 columns. Each column has an output of "0" or "1". Need to transpose column into row wise. Not sure if there's a way to provide column name dynamically.